# Material UI icon is not rendering in browser in React app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Here are the dependencies I installed:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.4.2",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.2",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.4.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  }
```

I try to use MUI icon:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Sidebar.css";
import AddCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddCircle";
function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="sidebar__header">
        <AddCircleIcon />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

But after using a MUI Icon when I save and look into the browser application does not render there. Is there anything which I am missing?

Comment: Are there any exceptions/errors in the developer console?

Comment: Try without Sidebar.css

Answer (score -2):

Using Option 1 of the usage section [here](https://v4.mui.com/components/icons/#usage) solved the same problem I had

So in your case try:

```
import AddCircleIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AddCircle";
```

Instead of:

```
import AddCircleIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AddCircle";
```